# Cast uint64_t var to void(*func)(...)

Tags: c++, casting, operating-system, void-pointers

Header File

```
extern void (*func)(char *c);
```

Source File

```
void (*func)(char *c) = NULL;
```

Main Source File

```
uint64 other;

// This arises error
func = (void*)(uintptr_t)other;
```

Actually, `other` is defined as void in bootloader and this is kernel, It is totally working in C but when I switched to C++ in kernel , It does n't cast

Error:  `invalid conversion from void* to void(*)(char c) [ -fpermissive]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast to the appropriate type: `(void(*)(char*)) other`.
(In contrast to C, C++ does not implicitly convert from `void*` to other types.)

Most people would define a type alias for readability, and use the idiomatic C++ cast:

```
using my_function = void(*)(char*);
my_function func = reinterpret_cast<my_function>(other);
```

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that implicit `void *` to function pointer fails in C as well.